# Verbform zu "Schorle"

Tags: word-usage, regional, verb-usage

Was man in Österreich als *G'spritzter* (etc.) versteht, heißt in weiten Teilen Deutschlands *Schorle*. Das Verb *spritzen* oder *aufspritzen* ist in diesem Fall gängig und bereitet keine Probleme.

Gibt es zu Schorle auch ein abgeleitetes Verb? Kann man zB Apfelsaft *schorlen*? "Schorle machen" ist mE etwas unelegant ...

Comment: In Deutschland muss man nicht den Sprudel in den Wein geben, sondern kann auch den Wein in den Sprudel geben. :) "Schorle mixen" kommt nicht so hilfsverbig daher.

Comment: @userunknown "mixen" hört sich für mich stark nach "gerührt und nicht geschüttelt" an - Beides ein bißchen kontraproduktiv für ein Schorle. Ich würde niemals "mixen" verwenden.

Comment: @tofro: Unabhängig davon, wie es sich für Dich anhört, bedeutet mixen nur mischen - bei Sprudel ist dazu weder ein Rührstab, noch ein Schüttelbecher nötig. Einfach mal ausprobieren. Du kannst auch "mischen" sagen.

Comment: Als ich »aufspritzen« las, dachte ich erst an einen ordentlichen Schuss Alkohol, der da reinkommt. Alternativ, dass mir der Saft irgendwie intravenös gegeben wird.

Comment: Schorle ist in Norddeutschland eigentlich nur als Apfelschorle verbreitet, und selbst anmischen tut das auch kaum einer. Auch kein Wirt. Insofern ist ein Verb dafür wohl verzichtbar.

Comment: Wirklich? Apfelschorle kommt fertig vorgemischt? Auch gut. Zumindest Weinschorle ist aber auch außerhalb Österreichs nicht gänzlich unbekannt.

Answer (score 7):

"Schorle machen" ist durchaus nicht unelegant und wird dort, wo "der/die/das Schorle" (das Genus ist regional unterschiedlich) gebraucht wird, auch rege verwendet.

Es gibt die Theorie, dass das *Schorle* ursprünglich vom Verb "schuren" abstammen soll, dass zumindestens der [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS19327#XGS19327) in einer Bedeutung von "*als schallwort, gleiten; oder sprudeln, rauschend flieszen*" noch kennt, heute aber vollkommen ungebräuchlich ist. Dieses Verb würde allerdings ausdrücken, was das Schorle selbst "*macht*", anstatt wie es *gemacht wird*.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen ist in diesem Kontext der Theologe Friedrich Schorlemmer.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ...doch, den darf man in diesem Kontext getrost vergessen.

Comment: Vergessen... wen doch gleich?

Comment: Was haben die evangelen den nun wieder angerichtet? Ich bin nur daran intressiert wenn es im Zusammenhang mit *schuren* steht, da mir das Wort gut gefällt. Ein schön rauschendes Sch gipfelnd in einem u geflogt von einem rasselndem r und endend in einem weichen n das "vernuschelt" werden kann im Alltag. Schön z.B. für über-dramatisierte sprachliche Nahaufnahmen.